# Regex - Match a string and not match another string in the same line

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am learning regular expressions. I was trying to print lines in a file that contain a particular string and do not contain another string.

I have a few lines in the file like

```
k 1 : abcd
jkjkj
l 1 : efgh
kjkjk
m 1 : abok
lklk
```

My intention is to match lines with `1 :` and not match `ab` on the same line.

My desired output should be `1 : efgh` (This line matches `1 :` and this line doesnot contain `ab`).

For this I have tried with regular expression `^((?!ab).*1 :*)*$`. But it does not work. Can some one point out where is the issue in my expression?

Comment: `shell` regular expressions aren't really regular expressions, they're called `file-globs` and have a much reduced syntax (and much reduced ability to fine-tune a search). AND is that a `PCRE` feature you're trying to use ( `(?!ab)`? If so, that not universally available in all *nix tools. Why not just `.*1 : [^a][^b][a-z][a-z]` . Good luck.

Comment: If you mean 'any tool usable in the `shell`', then you'll need to be more specific in your tags, maybe `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or `perl`? Use the appropriate tag to get the appropriate long-time readers to look at your Q. Good luck.

Comment: And you can try `.*1 : [!a][!b][a-z][a-z]` for a `bash` shell match. (don't have time to test now)  Good luck.

Comment: Pipe matching grep with inverse matching grep -v: `grep '1 :' file | grep -v 'ab'`

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comments, the shell does not support lookahead.
You could pipe your text through another program like `grep` to get your desired regex flavor (ie perl)

```
cat test.txt | grep --perl '1\s:(?!.*ab)'
```

returns

```
l 1 : efgh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the whole line, use `awk`:

```
awk !/ab/'  && '/1[[:space:]]:/ inputfile > outputfile
```

It outputs lines not containing `ab` and containing `1` + space + `:`.

To get a part of a line:

```
sed -E -n '/ab/!s/.*(1 :.*)/\1/p' inputfile > outputfile
```

Skip all lines containing `ab`, and extract capturing group value with `-n` + `p` option/flag.